# Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length with OData Client

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-365

I am using OData client to fetch the data from D365 AX. Following is the piece of code that is having the problem

```
var test = context.Employees
                    .AddQueryOption("$filter", $"EmployeeNumber eq '{query.EmployeeNumber}'");
                var result = await test.ExecuteAsync();
```

I am getting the following exception

> Message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Length cannot be less
>   than zero. Parameter name: length Stack Trace:
>               at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>             at Microsoft.OData.TypeUtils.ParseQualifiedTypeName(String qualifiedTypeName, String& namespaceName, String& typeName, Boolean& isCollection)
>              at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightContextUriParser.ResolveType(String typeName, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfMetadataConflict)
>             at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightContextUriParser.ParseContextUriFragment(String fragment, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfMetadataConflict, Boolean& isUndeclared)
>               at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightContextUriParser.ParseContextUri(ODataPayloadKind expectedPayloadKind, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfMetadataConflict)
>             at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightContextUriParser.Parse(IEdmModel model, String contextUriFromPayload, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean needParseFragment, Boolean throwIfMetadataConflict)
>            at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ReadPayloadStart(ODataPayloadKind payloadKind, PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Boolean isReadingNestedPayload, Boolean allowEmptyPayload)
>              at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPayloadKindDetectionDeserializer.DetectPayloadKind(ODataPayloadKindDetectionInfo detectionInfo)
>               at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightInputContext.DetectPayloadKind(ODataPayloadKindDetectionInfo detectionInfo)
>              at Microsoft.OData.Json.ODataJsonFormat.DetectPayloadKindImplementation(ODataMessageInfo messageInfo, ODataMessageReaderSettings settings)
>              at Microsoft.OData.Json.ODataJsonFormat.DetectPayloadKind(ODataMessageInfo messageInfo, ODataMessageReaderSettings settings)
>             at Microsoft.OData.ODataMessageReader.DetectPayloadKind()
>             at Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateODataMessageReader(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, ODataPayloadKind& payloadKind)
>               at Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
>              at Microsoft.OData.Client.MaterializeAtom..ctor(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
>              at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.CreateMaterializer(ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
>              at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)
>            at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>              at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>              at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
>          --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Kinldy help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is a conflict between your edmx string and client code generated by OData V4 Client Code Generator. I faced the same error and the reason was that I stored the edmx string in a separate file and I was using an old version of the file. Eventually, updating the edmx string file resolved the error.

Comment: I am storing the edmx file in the separate file as the metadata is too big to be stored in a string literal. I have updated the edmx file also, but I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you regenerate the client code too? If not, then I suggest you should regenerate it, update the edmx file and then try again.

Comment: If I click on "Run Custom Tool" by right-clicking the ODataClient.tt file, it will update the edmx and client code too. I have done that and it is not working yet.

Comment: Once you run the custom tool, make sure to point the Client Code to the newly generated edmx file.

Comment: Using ver 7.5.1 of the OData v4 Code Generator and version 7.5.2 of the OData nuget packages. After setting the ODataClient.tt file to use an external file, the only modification I needed to make was to replace all "" with " in the generated xml file.  Once I did that, I was able to run normal D365FO queries through the proxy.  Prior to that, I'd been coached to add an XML element to the top of the file and to remove the edmx:Edmx and edmx:DataServices elements, and to combine the two remaining Schema elements.  If I performed all those steps, I received the exact exception that the OP states.